# ContractObj not found in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, solidity, decentralized-applications

`$(document).ready(function(){`

`web3c = new Web3(ethereum);`

`const contractAddress="0x6eACA1A0406Def265a1ccbb193e09DA4Fd93635D";`
`const contractABI= [`
`{`
`"inputs": [`
`{`
`"internalType": "string",`
`"name": "messageData",`
`"type": "string"`
`}`
`],`
`"stateMutability": "view",`
`"type": "function",`
`"constant": true`
`}`
`],`

`ContractObj = new web3c.eth.Contract(contractABI,contractAddress);`

`})`

`async function setData(){`
`value = document.getElementById("dataValue").value;`
`tx= await ContractObj.methods.storeData(value).send({from: ethereum.selectedAddress});`
`console.log(tx);`
`}`
`async function getData(){`
`result = await ContractObj.methods.getData().call();`
`console.log(result);`
`alert("Result "+ result);`
`}`

Here ContractObj not defined error occuring ...I am a beginner..Anyone pls help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
ContractObj = new web3c.eth.Contract(contractABI,contractAddress);
```

to

```
let ContractObj = new web3c.eth.Contract(contractABI,contractAddress);
```

or

initialize ContractObj as a variable above your code.